# how to define current time value to uib-timepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my demo plnkr (http://embed.plnkr.co/SsdPPCQdAhdUldbeTK1E/)

my sample application having many days for the days i have various timing

my days `$scope.day = ['Sunday', 'Monday'];` but while applying time in ng-repeat i can"t able to get the current time in ui time-picker

without ng-repeat i can able to set the current time to it  using `$scope.mytime = new Date();`

how can we set current time using ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
$scope.days = [{day:'mon day',time: new Date}, {day:'tues day',time: new Date}];


<div class="" ng-repeat="day in days">
        <ul>
            <li>{{day.day}}</li>
            <input type="" name="" >
            <div uib-timepicker ng-model="day.time" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="1" minute-step="5" show-meridian="true"></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: exactly i want this output but i can"t able to push all the selected values to one array

Comment: just create a new array and push custome objects like `.push({day:sectedDay[i], time: dateTime[i]})`...